git clone over HTTP using project token fails with HTTP Basic: Access Denied
I'm currently trying to clone a repository from a gitlab instance that doesn't use SSL using a project access token with Maintainer permissions. The command I'm trying to run can be abstracted to the following:
git clone http://<random_string>:<project_token>@gitlabhost.com/path/to/repo.git -b <branch> --progress

I've already disabled SSL verification with git --global config http.sslVerify false just to get that out of the way.
However, the error I get, regardless of what I set random_string to be, is:
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
I've tried regenerating the project access token multiple times and I've tried downgrading the permissions of the project token to "Developer", but neither have resulted in a successful clone.
If it has any relevance, I've had success in cloning a repository using a project token from a gitlab instance that does use SSL, so is the fact that there's no SSL verification at all a factor here, or is there another issue?

All,
I've solved this issue by running a series of git config --global commands (which I'll post below), then when I'm prompted for a username and password, I simply enter the project token as the password, and I can authenticate. The series of git commands is the following:
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global credential.helper ""
git config --global credential.manager ""
git config --global core.modalPrompt false
git config --global core.askPass ""

